# nginx directory doesn't work with config

Tags: linux, nginx, server

What's wrong with my nginx config below?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name dashboard.abc.io;

    location / {
        root dashboard;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I got bad gateway error. I have file structure like below

```
/home/dashboard/index.html
```

Here's the log

```
10:10:42 [error] 23732#0: *2527 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 210.195.178.125, server: abc.io, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico"
```

Comment: Tou proxy every request to localhost:3000, so nginx never look for files

Comment: Btw, root path should be absolute